# Is wireless charging possible through an aluminium plate

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I got a mouse which has wireless charging capabilities a while back. I would like to take advantage of this. However, I currently have an extremely nice mousemat from grovemade I grabbed in a sale a while back https://grovemade.com/mouse-pads/ which I would like to keep using. My idea is simply place a wireless charging mousemat below it. However, the grovemade mousemat has an aluminium plate in it and so the wireless charing will induce eddy currents.

If you know how strong these eddy currents will be and/or whether that will make wireless charging impossible. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Pioneer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireless chargers operate in the frequency range of 100-200kHz. The skin depth in aluminum at that frequency is approx. 0.25mm. This means that a wireless charger will probably not work through solid aluminum sheets that are much thicker than a few layers of the kind of aluminum foil used in the kitchen. You can easily do the experiment yourself, of course. It might be possible to make it work by cutting thin slots into the metal, but that will most likely interfere with the mechanical stability of the mat. It's certainly worth experimenting with. Aluminum foil is cheap and can be easily cut with a pen knife. If even slotted aluminum foil won't work, then the likelihood that wireless charging with that technology can be made to work with a thicker metal plate is probably low.